Weekly chatroom discussions/talk session(s)
The chat room has been quite ronery these days. 
I was wondering if anyone would be interested in organizing a weekly discussions/talk sessions about things related to the Chinese language and culture. 
Topics of discussion might include: 

What are some of your favorite things to eat (from China or it's neighbors)? 
Ever have a questions about Chinese culture/history? Looking for a foreign pen pal?
Favorite/funny Chinese idioms/tongue twisters.
Word chain games in Chinese. (用途->途程, can't use the same character in
a chain twice, etc.) Helps improve vocabulary. ;)
Speak about your experience learning/teaching Chinese or living/visiting China. 
Mini-lessons on Chinese language, etiquette, or trivia.  
Anything else you'd like to talk about. 

For anyone interested in participating in a trial session, please leave your time zone information or suggest a time where we conveniently meet each other.
I was thinking each session should last anywhere from 30 minutes to an hour.
Alternatively, we could propose a topic of the week, be it a new trend or news article, and talk about that.
Yays? Nays?
I just wanted to get the idea out there for now and see who's interested.
I forgot to mention... I'm GMT -5 (US, EST). 

I'm currently at UTC/GMT +11 hours and would be interested in participating.

Just a suggestion; it may be better trying to get something like this running early next year after the end of the holiday season.

@xiaohouzi79 I was thinking, New Years Eve might be a good time to test this out. I mean as everyone celebrates their new year in their respective time zones, we can celebrate with them and talk about how they celebrate the new year and stuff.

@Krazer Check this discussion. :) This is for the admin part of the site. We'll also do the Language one.

I see you proposed it! :) Good... If I remember right, I'm in the GMT +1 (Italy). 
I didn't consider the Time Zones... We have two choices in this case:

Choose the time zone of the majority of those who join the event.
Make a sort of turn-changing thing: first this GMT, then the other one, then again this one, but always using the GMTs where we know there is a group of people. Choosing a GMT where there's only one person doesn't seem convenient, since this event is meant for a group of people.

These are just rough ideas! If I'm missing or forgetting something, please comment my post.

I was thinking a Saturday/Sunday would be more appropriate (for all you working ppl). For those on the other side of the date line it will be Sunday and for everyone else it will be Saturday. Once we get a consensus on the day, we can pick a good time for everyone.

I created a Chinese Chat room for speaking and practicing Chinese. :)

Well I quite like the idea, but I'm GMT +13 (New Zealand) which isn't super friendly with most of the world. Come February I'll be GMT +8 (back to China) so that could work.
This concept seems a little like the local Mandarin corner I used to attend, but online, which sounds pretty neat.

Check this discussion. :)

I am interested, but have a work schedule that may make it hard to participate guaranteed as hours change.  Obviously its only a first time trial event, but if it takes off maybe alternating the time it takes place for those who can't make a specific time in their zone could be good.

I'm interested. I'm at GMT-8. Maybe some word games and a Chinese caption writing game would be fun ice breakers.
I'll schedule an event for next Saturday at 1500 GMT. That's the best compromise I could think of for everyone, except Ciaocibai in New Zealand.
If one of the moderators schedules an event, it should get advertised on the site, so maybe we'll get more people showing up.
下个星期见。

Which should convert to: 11pm CST (China, all of it), 4pm CET (Italy, Central Europe), 2am EDT (Australia, Melbourne), 10am EST (US, New York, Boston, Eastern), 7am PST (US, Los Angeles, Seattle, Pacific), 3am/4am NZT/NZDT (New Zealand, Auckland). Let me know if I got the times wrong, daylight savings always messes me up. D:

The event page also adjusts the time match your browser's time zone.

@DonKirkby Check this discussion. :)

That's really a good proposal! I am in China(GMT +8) but I don't know if I am suitable for this discussion.

Check this discussion. :)

@Alenanno Thanks for the invitation. I'll be there if I don't have to overtime that day... I wish I would participate . Recently I have a lot of work to handle.
